# How to remove API activated by default in Google Cloud Platform projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Google Cloud Platform account with multiple projects.

Every time I create a new project, I have the following API activated by default.
[image]

- What are these APIs ?
- Are they optional ?
- Is it safe to disable them ?
- Is it possible to prevent Google Cloud Platform to add them by default when I create a new project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- These APIs are for very different purposes, you can find what are for [here](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enabled-service#default).
- In the previous link, it's mentioned that they can be disabled. Check how to disable them [here](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enable-disable#disabling).
- The documentation doesn't mention any risk or side effect of doing so.
- It doesn't look possible, as there is no mention of this in the public documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I somehow didn't find this information. Now the big question is why Google is doing this, but I think we'll never find out.